# Using $.when() / $.promise() with functions that have AJAX inside

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-deferred

Having a really hard time with this issue, and I know `$.when()` can be used like so (with multiple AJAX statements) to promise you when they have all finished.

http://jsfiddle.net/M93MQ/

```
    $.when(
        $.ajax({ url: '/echo/html/', success: function(data) {
            alert('request 1 complete')
          }
        }),

        $.ajax({ url: '/echo/html/', success: function(data) {
            alert('request 2 complete')
          }
        })
    ).then( function () { alert('all complete'); });
```

But this only works with raw `$.ajax()`, is there anyway to have this same functionality **with function calls**, that in turn have the ajax inside them (and other random logic) ?

Pseudo-code idea:

```
    // The functions having the AJAX inside them of course
    $.when(ajaxFunctionOne, ajaxFunctionTwo).then(function () {
        alert('all complete'); 
    });
```

Comment: What you're passing to `$.when()` is the **return value** of the function calls made to `$.ajax`; you're not passing it functions, in other words.  By the time that `$.when()` is called, the ajax operations have already started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, have the function return a promise object.

```
function ajaxFunctionOne() {
    return $.ajax(...)
}
function ajaxFunctionTwo() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    // on some async condition such as dom ready:
    $(dfd.resolve);
    return dfd.promise();
}

function ajaxFunctionThree() {
    // two ajax, one that depends on another
    return $.ajax(...).then(function(){
        return $.ajax(...);
    });
}   

$.when(ajaxFunctionOne(),ajaxFunctionTwo(),ajaxFunctionThree()).done(function(){
    alert("all complete")
});
```

Comment: Amazing... Thanks Kevin, I'm a dummy and I wasn't invoking the functions in the `$.when(functionName <-- no ()` plus, I didn't know it had to be within the `return` of it! Cleared it right up, your the man now dawg.